# Java-To_Date() inside Callable Statement

Tags: java, to-date, callable-statement

I need to execute the below procedure with 2 input param in Java. It should get executed successfully, there is no output param required.

Can anyone please help me with the code.

SQL Statement:

```
call pack_context.context_open(to_date('31-JULY-2016'),7);
```

Java Code:

```
CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
String proc = "{call pack_context.context_open(?,?)}";
callableStatement = con.prepareCall(proc);          
callableStatement.setInt(2, 7);
callableStatement.setDate(parameterName, x);//Need Help
```

Comment: your are expecting a String here, but you could change the query to accept a Date too. EDIT : Oups, didn't see your removed the to_date into the PC

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
callableStatement.setDate(parameterName, x);//Need Help
```

can be adjusted as shown below:

```
String myDate="31-JUL-2016"; // notice JUL, instead of JULY
// or use some other date string like yyyy-MM-dd
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
java.util.Date date = sdf.parse(myDate);
java.sql.Date d = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
callableStatement.setDate(parameterName, d);
// here parameterName should be the exact name as 
// in your procedure `pack_context.context_open`.
```

[setDate(String parameterName,
           Date x)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#setDate(java.lang.String,%20java.sql.Date)) requires the second parameter to be of the type java.sql.Date. The driver converts this to an SQL DATE value when it sends it to the database.